# Math.round() round numbers up not 2 decimals after comma

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
Math.round((7/2)).toFixed(2)
```

this code print: "4.00" while it should print 3.50. Where is a problem? How I can round this value whithout rounding-up?

Comment: _The Math.round() function returns the value of a number rounded to the nearest integer._ [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Comment: So how I can round this value without rounding-up ??

Comment: Why are you rounding at all? `(7/2).toFixed(2)` would yield "3.50".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it should print `"4.00"`, and that's why it is: You've rounded the `3.5` to `4`, then called `toFixed(2)` on `4`.

If you want `"3.50"`, then don't round it to a whole number first; `toFixed` will do rounding to the number of places you ask for (although rounding isn't required at all for `7/2` if you're outputting to two decimal places):

```
(7/2).toFixed(2)
```

E.g.:

```js
snippet.log((7/2).toFixed(2));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Example where `toFixed` actually does rounding:

```js
snippet.log((1.237).toFixed(2)); // "1.24"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```